# BottomSheetDialogFragment view becomes transparent only after device rotation

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, material-components-android

I want to create `BottomSheetDialogFragment` with rounded corners.

What I've done to achieve that:

```
    <style name="AppTheme.TransparentBottomSheetStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppTheme.TransparentBottomSheetStyle</item>
    </style>
```

`backdrop_shape.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="#00FF00"/>

    <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="24dp"
            android:topRightRadius="24dp"/>
</shape>
```

And bottom sheet layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/backdrop_shape"
        android:paddingBottom="18dp">
```

And code:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(BottomSheetDialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppTheme_BottomSheetDialogTheme)
    dialog?.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)
}
```

This works fine with `AppCompat` theme, but not with `MaterialComponents`:

[image]

As you can see, there is white background (I think, it's parent FrameLayout with id design_bottom_sheet).

And most interesting thing is that when I rotate the device (and then rotate it back), it becomes transparent as I wanted:

[image]

Is it bug or feature? How to fix it?

**Note:** I've tried all the solutions, that were posted on SO and other websites, they do not work on `MaterialComponents` too.

Comment: Could you try moving `setStyle(BottomSheetDialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppTheme_BottomSheetDialogTheme)` and `dialog?.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)` to `onCreate` instead of `onActivityCreated`?

Comment: @Aaron that worked, thanks. But `clearFlags` should be in `onActivityCreated`, or it would not work. Can you please post it as answer? I will accept it.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [DialogFragment.setStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#setStyle(int,%20int)):

> Call to customize the basic appearance and behavior of the fragment's
>   dialog. This can be used for some common dialog behaviors, taking care
>   of selecting flags, theme, and other options for you. The same effect
>   can be achieve by manually setting Dialog and Window attributes
>   yourself. **Calling this after the fragment's Dialog is created will
>   have no effect.**

I'm guessing that maybe `setStyle` should be called in or before `onCreate`.